# Formatting URLs in list to all have a trailing slash in python

Tags: python

There's some similar questions to this on stackoverflow but none do exactly what I want and my various attempts seem to fail.

I have a list of urls, some have trailing slash, others not... I want to check them and add a slash to those that don't.

```
url_list = ['http://google.com/somedirectory/', 'http://google.com/someotherdirectory/', 'http://google.com/anotherdirectory', 'http://google.com/yetanotherdirectory']

for url in url_list:
    if url[len(url)-1] != "/":
        url = url + "/"
    else:
        url = url

print url_list
```

returns the same list (last two urls still don't have a trailing slash)

```
['http://google.com/somedirectory/', 'http://google.com/someotherdirectory/', 'http://google.com/anotherdirectory', 'http://google.com/yetanotherdirectory']
```

why isn't it working? any ideas?

thanks :)

Comment: BTW, for proper URL string handling, consider using the `urlparse` module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why your changes don't work is that when you say `url = url + "/"` this doesn't edit `url` in-place in the list. If you want to do it this way, you might be better using `enumerate`:

```
for i, url in enumerate(url_list):
    if url[len(url)-1] != "/":
        url_list[i] = url + "/"

print url_list
```

We could neaten this further by changing `url[len(url)-1]` to `url[-1]`, which refers to the last character.

But while we're at it, why not use `.endswith()` and a list comprehension?

```
url_list = [u if u.endswith('/') else u + '/' for u in url_list]
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer... I suspected it wasn't changing the list (well obviously) but didn't know how to make it change it! Prefer the list comprehension idea too!

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing url_list. To keep the initial structure of your code, you could try this:

```
url_list = ['http://google.com/somedirectory/', 'http://google.com/someotherdirectory/', 'http://google.com/anotherdirectory', 'http://google.com/yetanotherdirectory']

new_urls = []
for url in url_list:
    if url[len(url)-1] != "/":
        new_urls.append(url + "/")
    else:
        new_urls.append(url)
url_list = new_urls

print url_list
```

You could also use .endswith() as suggested in another answer:

```
url_list = ['http://google.com/somedirectory/', 'http://google.com/someotherdirectory/', 'http://google.com/anotherdirectory', 'http://google.com/yetanotherdirectory']

new_urls = []
for url in url_list:
    if url.endswith('/'):
        new_urls.append(url)
    else:
        new_urls.append(url + "/")
url_list = new_urls

print url_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` variable is isolated from `url_list`. You can try this:

```
for i, url in enumerate(url_list):
    if url.endswith("/"):
        url_list[i] = url + "/"
print(url_list)
```